# Pointer to pointer to Struct

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct

I'm trying to do a C program that receives Strings and store them into structs dynamically, and after the passing strings part, I will show witch of them was written most. But I'm having trouble coding the pointers to pointers to structs. I'm trying to do something like the image that I draw [here](http://ctrlv.in/738692).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Word{
   char* palavra;
   int aparicoes;
} ;

struct word createWord(char* str){
   struct Word *newWord = malloc(sizeof(struct Word));
   assert(newWord != NULL);

   newWord->palavra = strdup(str);
   newWord->aparicoes = 1;

   return newWord;
}

int main (){
  char* tempString;
  struct Word** lista;
  int triggrer = 1;
  int i = 0;

  while (triggrer == 1)
  {
    scanf("%s", tempString);

    if (strcmp(tempString , "fui") == 0) 
      triggrer = 0;
    else 
    {

        while(*(&lista+i*sizeof(lista)) != NULL){
            i++;
        }

        if(i == 0){
            lista = malloc(sizeof(struct Word));

        }
        else{
            lista = (struct Word*) realloc(lista, sizeof(struct Word) + i*sizeof(struct Word));
        }

    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Deja vu..repeated...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318618/2173917)

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for the C and C++ tag

Comment: "I'm having trouble" Where? Was there an error? What was it?

Comment: The trouble isn't in the code, the problem is that I'm not succeeding to build this system.

Comment: SO exists to help with specific problems, not implement them for you. In what way are you not succeeding? What does this program do when compiled? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: "The trouble isn't in the code, the problem is that I'm not succeeding to build this system" Let me just say: **Huh?**

Comment: I'm not asking for a implement, I'm asking for a push, for a way of how can I do this, I'm looking in various websites but I still not understanding the pointer-pointer-struct concept neither implementation

Comment: It looks like you haven't quite understood one level of pointers yet, so some more reading (text, not code) would probably help. And `*(&lista+i*sizeof(lista))`? What you want is `lista[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no allocation of the pointers anywhere.

You need something like this:

```
lista = (struct Word**) malloc(sizeof(struct Word*));
*lista = NULL;
```

the above allocate one pointer to pointer to struct. the pointer to struct itself is null.

Now, not sure what you want to achieve by

```
while(*(&lista+i*sizeof(lista)) != NULL){
        i++;
    }
```

If you want to find the end of you array of pointers, presuming that the last pointer is NULL, then this is the code to do it:

```
while (*(lista + i) != NULL) i++;
```

Also, there are some typos in the code. This would compile and work. But I personally, recommend to use normal array of pointers (i.e. just keep the size of the array in another variable).

```
struct Word{
   char* palavra;
   int aparicoes;
} ;
struct Word * createWord(char* str){
   struct Word *newWord = (struct Word *)malloc(sizeof(struct Word));
   newWord->palavra = strdup(str);
   newWord->aparicoes = 1;
   return newWord;
}
int main()
{
  char tempString[1024];
  struct Word** lista;
  int triggrer = 1;
  int i = 0;
  lista = (struct Word**)malloc(sizeof(struct Word*));
  *lista = NULL;
  while (triggrer == 1)
  {
scanf("%s", tempString);

if (strcmp(tempString , "fui") == 0) 
  triggrer = 0;
else 
{

    while(*(lista+i) != NULL){
        i++;
    }

    lista = (struct Word**)realloc(lista, (i+1) * sizeof(struct Word*));
    *(lista+i) = createWord(tempString);
    *(lista+i+1) = NULL;
}
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what you are saying with
     while (*(lista + i) != NULL) i++;
Is that the pointer isn't pointing for the n next positions of memory, this n positions are somewhere else in the memory, and thats why makes no sense use the size of the variable to "jump" to the next position?

Comment: yes. well, lista points to the first pointer to pointer. lista + 1 points to the second pointer to pointer and so on. *(lista) points to the first struct, *(lista+1) points to the second and so on.